# size of machine 64 or 32 bit

Tags: unix

If I am working on a Unix machine, how could I know the size of the machine whether it is 64-bit or 32-bit machine?

Comment: Check the size of pointers if available in you language. Be more specific.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**AIX** you can do this:

```
getconf KERNEL_BITMODE
```

**HP-UX** you can do this:

```
getconf KERNEL_BITS
```

or just:

```
getconf -a | grep KERN
```

**Sun Solaris** you can do this:

```
isainfo -v
```

For Linux, yes, the `uname -a` should do the trick

Comment: as i am working on hp...getconf -a is not working... but getconf KERNEL_BITS is working fine.

Comment: android ? :D ... i manage to install LinuxOnAndroid (rooted device) and getconf -a | grep KERN returns nothing :( also uname -m, or arch returns armv71

Comment: These commands only show the installed kernel bit size mode. For possible CPU modes, look in `lscpu` or at [another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246014).

Answer (score 7):

You can type

```
uname -m
```

if i686 or i386 is appearing, you are working with 32 bit
if X86_64 is appearing, you are working with 64 bit

Answer (score 6):

I have to deal with a lot of Unix platforms and generally the best way I have found is to look at the output of "uname -a". For example, if you see something like  "i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux" in the output you know it's a 32 bit machine. If "amd64" shows up it's a 64. Sometimes it's a matter of trying to run a 64 bit programme. Sometimes it's RTFM.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to check the architecture of a machine you're on,

```
  %> uname -a
```

from the command line usually contains an indication in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `sizeof(int *)`. Should be 4 on 32 bit machines and 8 on 64 bit machines.

Comment: There's no reason why I can't target a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit computer.  Where I work, we haven't bothered changing some apps to 64 bits (although some eat memory by the gigabyte, and need to be run on 64-bit machines).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this at compile time - take a look [here](http://predef.sourceforge.net/prearch.html) for architecture macros you can test. You are probably looking for `__x86_64__`.