# Shell script to detect if system is a 32-bit or 64-bit

Tags: linux, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine whether a given Linux is 32 bit or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246007/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-linux-is-32-bit-or-64-bit)

Does anybody know how to create a shell script sh file that can shell one program if its a 64-bit system or shell another if its a 32-bit system?
Thank so much.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? We might be able to help you with a better overall solution if we knew what the actual problem is...

Comment: Does uname -i work for both platforms?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/how-to-determine-linux-kernel-architecture

Comment: What aspect of 32-bittiness vs 64-bittiness do you need to know?  There are 64-bit systems that can run 32-bit or 64-bit programs.  You can have a CPU capable of running 32-bit or 64-bit and the O/S booted might be a 32-bit kernel or a 64-bit kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if $(uname -m | grep '64'); then
  echo "ARCH: 64-bit"
else
  echo "ARCH: 32-bit"
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me -- all I get is a shell prompt: $. Simple string comparison, though, does the trick: if [ "$(uname -m | grep '64')" != "" ]; then

Answer (score 2):

Try `uname -m`: `x86_64` is a 64-bit kernel, `i686` is 32-bit kernel. Based on this, you can call either one program or the other.

Comment: That's only valid on x86, though...

Comment: This worked for me on my 32 bit machine.

Comment: @squiguy: it does work, as long as you are on an x86 platform.

Comment: @thkala I see, I logged into to a remote 32 bit machine.  My apologies.

Comment: Also, you might be running a "generic" x86 kernel, not an i686 one. There are various different strings you'd have to test for.

Comment: Tks everyone. I success with guide of twid.

Answer (score 1):

(In response to thkala's comment.)

```
if echo __SIZEOF_POINTER__ | cpp -E - - | grep '^8$' >/dev/null; then
    do_stuff
fi
```

Unlikely to work everywhere, but it works if cpp is from GCC. Has the advantage of detecting any 64-bit architecture, not just x64 (POWER, SPARC, IA64, whatever).

Comment: I was thinking about checking the value of `sizeof(void *)`, but that would require a compiler and would be about as reliable as running `file` on some random system binary...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether the processor is 64-bit, rather than the kernel, You can search for the long mode (-lm) flag on your system. It will be present on 64-bit, and not on 32-bit:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep lm`