# Why is the fgets function deprecated?

Tags: c, file-io, gnu, c99, buffer-overflow

From [The GNU C Programming Tutorial](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/fgets.html):

> The `fgets` ("file get string") function is similar to the gets
>   function. This function is *deprecated* -- that means it is obsolete
>   and it is strongly suggested you do not use it -- because it is
>   dangerous. It is dangerous because if the input data contains a null
>   character, you can't tell. Don't use `fgets` unless you know the data
>   cannot contain a null. Don't use it to read files edited by the user
>   because, if the user inserts a null character, you should either
>   handle it properly or print a clear error message. Always use
>   `getline` or `getdelim` instead of `fgets` if you can.

I thought the `fgets` function stops when it encounters a `\0` or `\n`; why does this manual page suggest a null byte is "dangerous" when `fgets` should handle the input properly? Furthermore, what is the difference between `getline` and `fgets`, and is the `fgets` function truly considered *deprecated* in the **C99** or future C standards?

Comment: `fgets()` does not stop on encountering a null byte; it only stops when it runs out of space, when it encounters a newline, or when it reaches EOF.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, `fgets` is not actually deprecated in C99 or the current standard, C11. But the author of that tutorial is right that `fgets` will not stop when it encounters a NUL, and has no mechanism for reporting its reading of such a character.

> The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n`
>   from the stream pointed to by `stream` into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file.

(§7.21.7.2)

GNU's `getdelim` and `getline` have been standardized in [POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html), so if you're targeting a POSIX platform, then it might not be a bad idea to use those instead.

**EDIT** I thought there was absolutely no safe way to use `fgets` in the face of NUL characters, but R.. (see comments) pointed out there is:

```
char buf[256];

memset(buf, '\n', sizeof(buf));  // fgets will never write a newline
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
```

Now look for the last non-`\n` character in `buf`. I wouldn't actually recommend this kludge, though.

Comment: So `fgets` keeps reading past null bytes, searching just for the newline character?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: that's right, and it won't tell you it did. There's no way to be sure that the first '\0' you find was added by `fgets` or not.

Comment: null bytes do not belong in **text** files. `fgets()` was designed to work with text files: using `fgets()` with files of binary data is not recommended.

Comment: @pmg: they might wind up in text files by accident, and it would be nice if `stdio` were more robust against such errors (it should at least report them, but it doesn't).

Comment: I wonder why `fgets` wasn't designed to return the number of bytes read.

Comment: @VilhelmGray: `stdio` tends to trust the user too much -- it just doesn't anticipate long lines, null characters in text files, etc. It's from the 1970s, when defensive programming wasn't deemed as important as it is now (no internet, no script kiddies trying to break into your system, no noob users that will spam you when they screw up a text file).

Comment: @larsman: Actually you can know if you pre-fill the buffer right.

Comment: @R..: how? By filling it with `\n` then searching for the last non-newline?

Comment: Yep, if you pre-fill the buffer with `'\n'` then you can search for the first newline; if it's followed by a 0 byte, that newline was the last read byte. Otherwise, the byte before that newline was the last read byte.

Comment: @R..: I'd rather reimplement `fgets` with a saner interface than do that, but I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The only way to reimplement `fgets` is by repeatedly calling `getc`, which will be many times slower than the trick I just described.

Comment: @R..: probably, but when I/O is not the bottleneck I prefer my code clean.

Comment: Yes I would not do that inline in other code but as a function it's reasonable.

Comment: `// fgets will never write a newline` comment is unclear.  Certainly a `'\n'` is written to the buffer on many `fgets()` calls.  Did you mean `// fgets will never read after a newline`?

Comment: `memset(buf, '\n', sizeof(buf));  fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);` **is** good except for a) The C spec is weak/inadequate on the stability of contents after the appended null character, so searching from the end is on thin ice.  Searching from the beginning past a null character is of similar concern.  b) When an input error occurs - buffer is explicitly undefined  - of course, no need to read the buffer then.

Answer (score 8):

This is just GNU propaganda. In no official sense is `fgets` deprecated. `gets` however is dangerous and deprecated.

Comment: `gets` was actually *removed* from the 2011 ISO C standard. (It was not officially deprecated or obsolescent in C99.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Section 7.26.9 of ISO/IEC 9899:1999 TC3 says "The `gets` function is obsolescent, and is deprecated." so I believe that `gets` was officially deprecated in C99.

Comment: Was that language added in one of the TC's, or was it in the original publication of C99?

Comment: @R..: It was added by TC3.

Comment: TC3 was published in 2007 (2007-11-15 according to its cover).  So `gets()` was not deprecated in 1999, but it was deprecated in an update to C99 published in 2007, about 4 years before C11 was published.