# Java accepts one (1) multiline string from stdin

Tags: java, stdin

I am writing a program that can either accepts a ".sql" file or accepts an SQL statement from the stdin. The problem comes form stdin:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream( System.in));
System.out.println("Enter SQL statements");
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    stringBuilder = stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");
}
sqlQuery=stringBuilder.toString();
```

It is modified from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297629/5531761). But when I enter or paste the statement(s) into the terminal, it does not go to the next step, instead the statement keeps appending `"\n"`. I want the user input to end after they hit `enter` (similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871127/how-to-read-string-from-stdin-until-meet-blank-lines) but in Java). How do I do it?

Comment: So check whether the user entered an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collect all the input until a double new-line (a blank line), you can set a custom delimiter on the `Scanner`, using a regex, and it will collect the input with a single call to `scanner.next()`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter SQL statements");

scanner.useDelimiter("\n\n"); // an empty line
String sqlQuery = scanner.next();
scanner.reset(); // resets the delimiter
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you present anticipates that the input will be terminated by the end of the stream with which the `Scanner` is associated, not by the end of a single line -- see how the `scanner.nextLine()` invocation is inside a `while` loop?

If you want to read only one line then get rid of the loop.  Moreover, if you're not concatenating multiple lines, then you don't need a `StringBuilder` either.  Be sure that this is what you want, however, for it is relatively common for SQL statements to be written in multiline format.

Comment: Note: text-mode SQL interfaces commonly accept multiline input.  They generally look for some sort of delimiter to recognize the end of a query, such as a period or semicolon on a line by itself.

Comment: But some sql statements consist of multiple commands, such as multi-table insertion or creating a view and  then extracting data from it

Comment: @DylanChensky, multiple commands are not an issue, as you can just enter them sequentially.  Multiline *individual* commands are a different matter, and if you want to support these then you have a fundamental problem: how is the program supposed to recognize a given line as the last in a command, vs. expecting additional lines to follow?  I already said a word or two about that in my previous comment.