# How can i get every line of a text file separately using C

Tags: c

supposing i have a text file with this content :

```
this is the first line . 
this is the second line . 
this is the third line .
```

my point is to get every line in a separate string variable .

i tried something like this

```
   do { fgets(ch,1000,f);printf("%s \n",ch); } while(strlen(ch)!=0);
```

whith "f" is a pointer to my file and ch my string variable .

Comment: i'm trying to take each line and applicate other function on it 'separately' not displaying the whole content of the text file on console .

Comment: Use malloc or realloc.

Comment: Use an array of `char*` pointers. Read each line into an array, use `malloc()` to allocate a string to hold the contents, copy the string, and put the pointer in the array.

Comment: Your own attempt ought to work (for lines less than 999 characters), but change the test to check the return result of `fgets` itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use fgets(), you can try something like that:

```
char ch[999];   
FILE * f;
f = fopen( "test.txt" , "r");
if (f) 
{
    while(fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), f) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", ch);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Then you can use the variable ch as you want.

Comment: You should include a note about how [a null character in the input stream can lead to unexpected results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16323185/2615940) when using fgets().

Comment: @skrrgwasme: you should note that `fgets` is to be used on text files, and "null bytes do not belong in **text** files. fgets() was designed to work with text files: using fgets() with files of binary data is not recommended. – pmg" (from a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323185/why-is-the-fgets-function-deprecated#comment23375681_16323215) in there).