# getline how to limit amount of input as you can with fgets

Tags: c, security, fgets, getline

[GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html)

This quote is from the GNU manual

> Warning: If the input data has a null character, you can’t tell. So
>   don’t use fgets unless you know the data cannot contain a null. Don’t
>   use it to read files edited by the user because, if the user inserts a
>   null character, you should either handle it properly or print a clear
>   error message. We recommend using getline instead of fgets.

As I usually do, I spent time searching before asking a question, and I did find a similar question on Stack Overflow from five years ago:
[Why is the fgets function deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323185/why-is-the-fgets-function-deprecated)

Although GNU recommends `getline` over `fgets`, I noticed that `getline` in `stdio.h` takes any size line. It calls `realloc` as needed. If I try to set the size to 10 char:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 10;
    size_t characters;

    buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if( buffer == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Type something: ");
    characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
    printf("%zu characters were read.\n",characters);
    printf("You typed: '%s'\n",buffer);
    return(0);
}
```

In the code above, type any size string, over 10 char, and getline will read it and  give you the right output.

There is no need to even `malloc`, as I did in the code above — `getline` does it for you. I'm setting the buffer to size 0, and `getline` will `malloc` and `realloc` for me as needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 0;
    size_t characters;

    printf("Type something: ");
    characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
    printf("%zu characters were read.\n",characters);
    printf("You typed: '%s'\n",buffer);
    return(0);
}
```

If you run this code, again you can enter any size string, and it works. Even though I set the buffer size  to 0.

I've been looking at safe coding practices from CERT guidelines [www.securecoding.cert.org](http://www.securecoding.cert.org)

I was thinking of switching from `fgets` to `getline`, but the issue I am having, is I cannot figure out how to limit the input in `getline`. I think a malicious attacker can use a loop  to send an unlimited amount of data, and use up all the ram available in the heap?

Is there a way of limiting the input size that `getline` uses or does `getline` have some limit within the function?

Comment: An attacker can only send an unlimited amount of data by using an unlimited amount of network bandwidth, so it's not much of  a threat. Anyway, getline will return failure if it cannot realloc a big enough buffer; you can limit the heap size if you're really worried about it.

Comment: I agree, but they can use up all my available memory in the heap. I don't have that much ram.

Comment: There is no limit other than that which is encountered through exhausting resources (memory).  It is a problem; there isn't a solution other than 'code it yourself' (that I know of).  You can (and should) free the memory.  You can learn how much memory is allocated from the `bufsize` variable you pass.  Note that even if you read on `/dev/null`, the chances are `getline()` will allocate memory for you if you pass in a zero buffer size.  One issue is how any modified variant should report 'reached limit before encountering newline (delimiter for `getdelim()`) or EOF'.  Another value like `-2`?

Comment: @jonathan: [setrlimit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) can be used to limit a process's (virtual) memory usage. I honestly don't think it's a problem in this use case, but it's certainly possible to restrict vmem growth. Getline returns a negative value and sets `errno` to `ENOMEM` if `realloc` fails.

Comment: rici I did not know about `setrlimit`, but i think fgets is good enough, I don't think users will input '\n' into  there input, and if they do, the string will be truncated. When i was learning C, I used K&R `getline` all the time, never had a problem with it. It does read NULL and it returns the string length, which you can use to ignore any NULL if they exist in your text.

Comment: Using `setrlimit()` is a blunderbuss — but I guess it can do the job.  I'd like a function like `fgets()` to return the count of the characters read, so you can detect embedded null bytes.  The K&R book has a `getline()` — actually, 4 variant implementations all with a wholly different interface from the POSIX `getline()` — that returns the number of bytes read.  That is a useful design; it incorporates the best of both `fgets()` and `getline()`.

Comment: @Manny_Mar: 'there input' --> 'their input'; and you probably meant `'\0'` rather than `'\n'` since users will type newlines.  You can edit your own comments if you're quick.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffle Your right, Just looked at K&R getline code, and it is a `'\n'` not a `'\0'`. I should have looked over the code before posting it. I cannot edit the above answer, must have a limit on how many times it can be edited.

Comment: @Manny_Mar — You can edit a comment for up to five minutes; after that, it is frozen.  Hence the "if you're quick" part of my comment.  There's also the 'copy, delete, and add new comment' technique — or 'copy, add new comment, delete old comment'.  It works.

Comment: I wanted to look at K&R code, before commenting, I thought it was `'\0'` but when i looked it as `'\n'` took me a little time to look.

Comment: @jonathan: the point of `setrlimit` is precisely to avoid excess vmem usage; if you are concerned about that, then it's likely that `getline` will not be the only possible vmem hog and setting the limit globally will be appropriate. Otherwise, I honestly don't see the point of artificially limiting the length of an input line. And I say that as someone who has not infrequently had to find awkward workarounds for programs which impose such limits. I agree that the fgets prototype sucks.

Comment: `fgets` is ok, don't think will get to many `NULL` when reading input from users. Although K&R first version of getline will read `NULL`, and has a fix size you set manually. It only stops if hits `EOF` or newline. It used this test `for (i=0; i< lim -1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)` It adds the `'\n'` at the end of the string and returns the size of the string, including the `'\n'`.

Comment: Normally, when you write console utilities, you're writing them for other people to run on *their* machines, so it's not your possibly limited resources which are being overcommitted. I don't see a use case for either getline or fgets in a server, because it's pretty rare to use a FILE* for socket communication, and there are excellent reasons to avoid any potentially blocking call on a socket regardless of resourcing issues. MISRA suggests that FILE* shouldn't normally be used in embedded systems. So where is the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Using fgets is not necessarily problematic, all the gnu manual tells you is that if there's a '\0'-Byte in the file, so will there be in your buffer. You won't be able to tell if the null-delimiter in your buffer is the actual end of the file or just a null within the file. This means you can read a 100 char file into a 200 char buffer and it will contain a 50 char c-string.

The stdio.h readline in fact doesn't appear to have any sane length limitation so fread might be viable alternative.

Unlinke C [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) and C++ [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), C++ [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) is limited to `count` characters

Comment: I removed the c++ tag, looks like getline is not the same in C as in C++

Answer (score 1):

The GNU manual is just bad. Limiting the input length is usually the right thing to do, especially if input is untrusted, and `fgets` does this correctly. `getline` cannot be used safely in such a context.

Comment: The GNU manual is pointing out a genuine problem with `fgets()`; it is not 'fessing up to a different but also potentially severe problem in their preferred replacement, `getline()` — which is unusual because it is documented to return `-1` (rather than `EOF` — though the two are usually the same) when it encounters EOF (with no data read).  If `fgets()` (or a variant) returned the number of characters read instead of returning a pointer to the start of the string — something the calling code already knows, dammit — then `fgets()` would have distinct merits.