# Meaning of "pc" in target architecture triplet

Tags: cross-compiling, target-platform

I've successfully compiled things with the target i686-linux-gnu and i686-pc-linux-gnu; they seem to be equivelent. What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some tips looking at [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Configuration.html) where you can read:

> The configure script should also take an argument which specifies the type of system to build the program for. This argument should look
>   like this:
>
> ```
> cpu-company-system
> ```
>
> For example, an Athlon-based GNU/Linux system might be
>   ‘i686-pc-linux-gnu’. The configure script needs to be able to decode
>   all plausible alternatives for how to describe a machine. Thus,
>   ‘athlon-pc-gnu/linux’ would be a valid alias

Moreover i686 conventionally refers to a 32-bit kernel whereas x86_64 refers to a 64-bit kernel as you can see in this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246007/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-linux-is-32-bit-or-64-bit).

Particularly instructive is the [config.guess shell script](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD) that shows you all the possibilities taken into account when the build type is not specified by an option or argument.

Comment: Oh, so "linux-gnu" is one term in the triplet. Thanks!